# PHP: How to send confirmation mail by clicking link in existing mail?

Tags: php, email

When a customer sends an appointment request the service provider gets an email. I want to include a link in this email, which would trigger an email that would be sent directly to customer.

Following code just opens the blank page in browser when the link in the email is clicked and the email is not sent. What am I doing wrong?

```
<a href='?confirmation'>Confirm appointment request</a>

<?php
function confirmFunction() {
    $to = $appointment->get_order()->billing_email;
    $subject = 'Appointment confirmed';
    $msg = "Appointment confirmed.\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg);
}

if (isset($_GET['confirmation'])) {
    confirmFunction();
}
?>
```

Comment: E-mails don't have a relative context to work with. Links need to be absolute, using a FQDN.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what exactly to do :/

Comment: The link in the e-mail has to be the full URL, e.g. `http://my-domain.com/?confirmation`. It can't be relative as you have in your example.

Comment: Your mail () fuction use is wrong

Comment: I added an URL and deleted the last parameter of mail function. Still nothing happens.